# How to drop string values from pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df:

```
col1  col2
A      1
B      2
1      string
2      3
C      more string
```

How can I drop all the rows where col2 contains a string?

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: what is the datatype of numbers in `col2` ?

Comment: I can write a statement to loop through the df to find the type of each value, and drop that way, it just seems clunky and like it should be less text to get what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
df[pd.to_numeric(df['col2'], errors='coerce').notnull()]
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2
0    A    1
1    B    2
3    2    3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
df = df[df['col2'].apply(lambda x: type(x) != str)]
```

The `apply` function ouputs `True` for every row that is not a string. For strings, it yields false. Then all rows with `True` are selected from the data frame.